# Exclude .install files from Sonar for duplicate code detection in Drupal

Tags: drupal, duplicates, sonarqube

We have configured Sonar to analyze our Drupal code for coding standards. Also, detecting duplicated code using CPD.
In the Duplications section I have given *.install as pattern to allow Sonar to exclude .install files. But this is not reflecting in Sonar. What is the correct pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Your should try `**/*.install`. This excludes `.install` files from every directory, but       `*.intsall` only excludes from the base directory.